# Pelican i18n subsites menu items override

Tags: python, html, localization, internationalization, pelican

I am building a static site with [Pelican](http://blog.getpelican.com/) and the [i18n subsites plugin](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/tree/master/i18n_subsites).

The way I understand it, you can override settings in pelicanconf.py with this plugin, but I don’t think the way I did it is working.

Pelicanconf.py:

```
I18N_SUBSITES = {
    'nl': {
        'SITENAME': 'Robin Berghuijs Design',
        'INDEX_SAVE_AS': 'nieuws.html',
        'MENUITEMS': [
            ('Nieuws','nieuws.html'),
        ],
    },
    'en': {
        'SITENAME': 'Robin Berghuijs Design',
        'INDEX_SAVE_AS': 'news.html',
        'MENUITEMS': [
            ('News','news.html'),
        ],
    }
}
```

Index.html output:

```
<nav id="menu"><ul>
    <li><a href="./pages/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul></nav><!-- /#menu -->
```

base.html template:

```
    {% for title, link in MENUITEMS %}
        <li><a href="{{ link }}">{{ title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
```

I get no errors upon site generation. [More detail here](https://gist.github.com/Flobin/f3d8bf587d5cee597396).

Running pelican with --debug [gives this](https://gist.github.com/Flobin/c7bd3cc2faa6135803dd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the i18n subsites plugin was creating two new sites, with the old one left in the output folder. So there was a site in `output/`, one in `output/nl/`, and one in `output/en/`. Adding `DELETE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = True` and `'OUTPUT_PATH': '',` to the Dutch i18n subsites settings solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the same understanding of how the settings could be overwritten, but ended up using this "workaround" where `DEFAULT_LANG` gets value `"nl"` or `"en"` based on the localized page that Pelican is currently generating.

```html
{% for page_title, page_link in I18N_SUBSITES[DEFAULT_LANG].MENUITEMS %}
    <li><a href="{{ page_link }}">{{ page_title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```